# How to create a dynamic sql WHERE clause in python accepting an undefined number of parameters

Tags: python, sql

For example i would like to have several date ranges such as :

```
[
{"start_date": 20210705, "end_date": 20210710},
{"start_date": 20220805, "end_date": 20220810}
]
```

And i would like to get something like that :

```
'business_date between 20210705 AND 20210710 OR business_date between 20220805 AND 20220810'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like that :

```
date_id_query = ""

for i in date_ranges :
  date_id_query += f"date_id between {list(i.values())[0]} AND {list(i.values())[1]} OR "

date_id_query = ''.join(date_id_query.rsplit('OR', 1))
```

Comment: How was what you *actually* did different from this?